# Vue js form pushed to firebase but database data is empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I got a problem here when I push the form and I check on Firebase I see that the data is pushed but the data is empty.

I imported the firebase config file to my ProfileInfo.vue file.

```
import { db } from '../../config/db';
```

This is my **method** what I use.

```
AddProfile() {
        this.$firebaseRefs.Profile.push({
            firstName: this.profileData.firstName,
            lastName: this.profileData.lastName,
            phoneNumber: this.profileData.phoneNumber,
            adress: this.profileData.adress,
            gender: this.profileData.gender,
            personalEmail: this.profileData.personalEmail,
            companyName: this.profileData.companyName,
            chamberOfCommerceNumber: this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber,
            street: this.profileData.street,
            houseNumber: this.profileData.houseNumber,
            zipCode: this.profileData.zipCode,
            location: this.profileData.location,
            companyEmail: this.profileData.companyEmail
        })
        this.profileData.firstName = '';
        this.profileData.lastName = '';
        this.profileData.phoneNumber = '';
        this.profileData.adress = '';
        this.profileData.gender = '';
        this.profileData.personalEmail = '';
        this.profileData.companyName = '';
        this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber = '';
        this.profileData.street = '';
        this.profileData.houseNumber = '';
        this.profileData.zipCode = '';
        this.profileData.location = '';
        this.profileData.companyEmail = '';
        // this.$router.push('/internship')
        console.log('Added to database');
    }
```

**Now the data is empty from my Firebare:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting anything other than empty strings? That's exactly what your code is providing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Setting them to empty strings happens after the call to the database.

Comment: @mustafa: we have no way to know what `this.profileData` looks like, and in fact Doug's guess is not unreasonable. Why do you think/know that `this.profileData` is anything but a bunch of empty properties? For example: if you `console.log(JSON.Stringify(this.profileData))` right before the call to `this.$firebaseRefs.Profile.push({ ...`, what is the output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I get this: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)

Comment: Hmm... not sure what that is, although I just noticed I had a typo earlier: it's `JSON.stringify` with a lowercase `s`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen now I get this: `{"firstName":"","lastName":"","phoneNumber":"","adress":"","citizenship":"","gender":"","personalEmail":"","companyName":"","chamberOfCommerceNumber":"","street":"","houseNumber":"","zipCode":"","location":"","companyEmail":""}`

Comment: It is strange I took the same code from my project I changed only the table name and the v-bind names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210521/discussion-between-mustafa-bolat-and-frank-van-puffelen).